# the verbosity of "(SELECT * FROM A)"?

Tags: postgresql, relational-algebra

This might be a novice question. But sometimes, I find it **necessary** to use things like `(SELECT * FROM A)` in doing relational algebra in SQL (instead of using the relation `A` itself).

For example, when trying to work on the `UNION` of two relations `A` and `B` having the same structure, the following

```
SELECT * FROM (A UNION B) t;
```

generates a syntax error (with PostgreSQL 9.x).

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
```

And I had to do

```
SELECT * FROM ((SELECT * FROM A) UNION (SELECT * FROM B)) t;
```

My questions are:

Is the verbosity of the subquery `(SELECT * FROM A)` really necessary in the SQL language (or am I missing something about better way to write it)? Why can't the relations `A` and `B` be used directly here?

Is `(SELECT * FROM A)` equivalent to `A` in relational algebra? What does the expansion `(SELECT * FROM A)` buy us? When is the long form required?

Comment: Related: [Is there a shortcut for SELECT * FROM in psql?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30276023/939860)

Comment: Note that all those parentheses are unnecessary. Just like the sub-query: `select * from a union select * from b` will do just fine

Answer (score 7):

If you want shorter syntax in SQL, there is the [`TABLE name` syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-TABLE) that you can use - where `name` is a table name (base table or view or cte):

```
SELECT * FROM ((TABLE A) UNION (TABLE B)) t ;
```

The parentheses are not needed:

```
SELECT * FROM (TABLE A UNION TABLE B) t ;
```

and you could even write:

```
TABLE A UNION TABLE B ;
```

---

Regarding whether the syntax is ISO/ANSI SQL, I found this in a (copy of a) draft of SQL 2011:

**6.41 `<multiset value constructor>`**

**Function**

Specify construction of a multiset.

**Format**

```
<multiset value constructor> ::=
    <multiset value constructor by enumeration>
    | <multiset value constructor by query>
    | <table value constructor by query>

<multiset value constructor by enumeration> ::=
    MULTISET <left bracket or trigraph> <multiset element list> <right bracket or trigraph>

<multiset element list> ::=
    <multiset element> [ { <comma> <multiset element> }... ]

<multiset element> ::=
    <value expression>

<multiset value constructor by query> ::=
    MULTISET <table subquery>

<table value constructor by query> ::=
    TABLE <table subquery>
```